# Automate AMI Update in EC2

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am using cloudformation template to create 4 EC2 instances behind an ELB. These instances will be associated with a launch config and Auto scaling group.
We update our AMIs every 2 months. Now if I have to update the AMIs without any down time what would be the best strategy. I am using jenkins for orchestration.

The plan that I have in mind is this
Template #1- creates ASG and Launch config
tempate #2 Creates/Updates ELB with new instances created

First execution
1. Create a cloudformation stack comprising of launch config and Autoscaling group.
This will launch 4 EC2 instances and bootstrap the application
2. Create 2nd  template that will create ELB and bind the 4 instances created to the ELB. It will also bind the ELB to the ASG

When AMI has to be udated
1. Execute the first template that will create a new (ASG)The idea is to create new and not update the ASG since the ELB has to continue sending traffic to the old ASG until all instances are up and running.

2. Once the servers are up, the 2nd template will update the ELB with the new instances and update new auto scaling group with the new ELB.
3. delete the old stack.

Is there anything better to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud formation has support for this natively.  Take a look at the [Update Policy Attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html) documentation.